# How to use container_of with member of type pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, linux-kernel

I'm trying to use container_of macro in Linux Kernel but getting this compile time issue.

```
./include/linux/build_bug.h:78:41: error: static assertion failed: "pointer type mismatch in container_of()"
 78 | #define __static_assert(expr, msg, ...) _Static_assert(expr, msg)
```

Snippet is something like this

```
enter code here
#include <stddef.h>

struct abc {
    // ... members of struct abc
};

struct ContainingStruct {
    int someData;
    double someDouble;
    struct abc *somePointer;  // Assuming this is a pointer member
};

int main() {
    struct ContainingStruct myStruct;
    struct abc innerStruct;

    myStruct.somePointer = &innerStruct;

    // Using container_of to get a pointer to the containing structure
    struct ContainingStruct *containingPtr = 
    container_of(myStruct.somePointer, struct ContainingStruct, 
                 somePointer);

   // Now containingPtr points to the entire struct, and you can access 
      its members
   containingPtr->someData = 42;
   containingPtr->someDouble = 3.14;

// ...

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Are you writing a Linux kernel module or hacking on the kernel itself?  If not, then you should ignore anything you see in or know about the kernel headers and sources.  The kernel sources rely on a variety of C implementation details that general-purpose software cannot safely rely on.

Comment: Trying to update in Kernel itself, Source code I presented here is more for example.

Comment: The assertion is complaining that the type pointed to by the first macro argument is not compatible with the type of `(struct ContainingStruct).somePointer`.  That's trivially true of the code presented, because the first macro argument, `ptr`, is not even declared.  We can't say what the problem is in the real code, but my wild guess would be an incorrect level of indirection.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, is there an example in Kernel source where last argument used for container_of() is pointer rather than object, for example here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/probes/uprobes/actions-arm.c#L109 , asi here is struct arch_probes_insn asi; but if it is struct arch_probes_insn *asi, this issue is triggered.

Comment: The first argument is supposed to be a pointer to the member.

Comment: @Milan, a pointer *is* an object.  There are no special rules around pointers here.  If the member has a pointer type, then a pointer to that member has a pointer-to-pointer type, just as if the member has type `int`, a pointer to that member would have pointer-to`int` type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, this is what I am originally trying to do, may be you can help with it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77655780/how-to-access-this-structure-member

Answer (score 1):

From [`linux/kernel.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/include/linux/kernel.h):

```
/**
 * container_of - cast a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @ptr:    the pointer to the member.
 * @type:   the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
    const typeof(((type *)0)->member) * __mptr = (ptr); \
    (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member)); })
```

This says the first argument of the macro should be *the pointer to the member*.

However, your code is passing in the member, not a pointer to it.

For clarity, I have illustrated the fix by creating a variable of suitable pointer type, and passing that to your macro:

```
struct abc **ptr_to_member = &myStruct.somePointer;
struct ContainingStruct *containingPtr = 
container_of(ptr_to_member, struct ContainingStruct, 
             somePointer);
```