# how to access this structure member

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have struct which is defined here:

```
struct resctrl_schema {
    struct list_head                list;
    char                            name[8];
    enum resctrl_conf_type          conf_type;
    struct rdt_resource             *res;
    u32                             num_closid;
    int                             max_data_width;
};
```

Now I need to access its member conf_type from the following function (with out changing its definition) tried using container_of macro

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morse/linux.git/tree/drivers/platform/mpam/mpam_resctrl.c?h=mpam/snapshot/v6.3#n1142

```
@@ -990,9 +994,12 @@ int resctrl_arch_update_domains(struct rdt_resource 
                                                     *r, u32 closid)
    struct rdt_domain *d;
    enum resctrl_conf_type t;
    struct resctrl_staged_config *cfg;
  + struct resctrl_schema *my_container;

    lockdep_assert_cpus_held();
    lockdep_assert_irqs_enabled();
  +       
  + my_container = container_of(r, struct resctrl_schema, res);
```

but seeing compilation error:

```
 ./include/linux/build_bug.h:78:41: error: static assertion failed: 
 "pointer type mismatch in container_of()"
 78 | #define __static_assert(expr, msg, ...) _Static_assert(expr, msg)
```

and this function is called from  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morse/linux.git/tree/fs/resctrl/ctrlmondata.c?h=mpam/snapshot/v6.3#n350

Comment: The function `parse_cbm()` gets a `struct resctrl_schema` as argument `s`, so maybe you could pass `s->conf_type` as an argument to `resctrl_arch_update_domains()` ? I'm not familiar with Linux, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre] directly in the question, not as links to external sites.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, made the update , what I tried, and the issue I am seeing.

Comment: What is being passed to the function, `&res` or `&resctrl_res`?

Comment: I think the `res` argument should be `resctrl_res`. See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morse/linux.git/tree/drivers/platform/mpam/mpam_resctrl.c?h=mpam/snapshot/v6.3#n1089 for example.

Comment: No, this would not work, resctrl_res is part of mpam_resctrl_res but what I am after is resctrl_schema that has member res, struct rdt_resource  *res,  original struct is this,
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morse/linux.git/tree/include/linux/resctrl.h?h=mpam/snapshot/v6.3#n251

Comment: The first parameter to `container_of` should be a **pointer to the field**. It doesn't work with a **value** of that field, even if the value is a pointer by itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, what I conclude here, it's impossible to make the container_of work with out changing the definition of resctrl_arch_update_domains in my case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, also, "The first parameter to container_of should be a pointer to the field", It should be address of the field , if the field is pointer than its address not the value, right ?

Comment: "what I conclude here, it's impossible to make the container_of work with out changing the definition of resctrl_arch_update_domains in my case." - When a structure and operations on it are defined, it is usually specified which of fields could be used for `container_of`. It is unlikely that a user of that structure could use other fields for container_of without changing operations on that structure. So yes, `container_of` is unlikely to help you in your task.

Comment: "It should be address of the field , if the field is pointer than its address not the value, right ?" - Semantically, you need to pass to `contained_of` an **address** of the field in some structure instance. But that address should have the same **type**, as one of the **pointer-to-field**. In you case, the type should be `struct rdt_resource**`.